# Google Action MEDIA_STATUS not working for STOP and PAUSE events

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

In my google function, i am using 'Media Status' handler to catch event action while audio playing. I am able to get event on the handler only when the current playing audio completes playing. When I pause or stop the audio I am not able to make the 'Media Status' handler get triggered.

actions-on-google : 2.6.0  using node module.

```
conv.ask(`<speak>XXXXXX</speak>`);
conv.ask(new MediaObject({
                name: AAAA,
                url: ${url},
                description: XXXXX,
                icon: {
                    url: BBBBB,
                    accessibilityText: 'Media icon'
                },
            }));
const suggestions3 = new Suggestions('Skip', 'Go back', 'Exit');
            conv.ask(suggestions3);
```

Can anyone help me how can i trigger the handler on PAUSE or STOP events.

Answer (score 0):

The STOP and PAUSE events are currently only available for Actions developed using Actions Builder.